# Integrating Skype for Business with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, skype-for-business

We have a Xamarin.Forms application (using FreshMvvm). This app needs to include video chat functionality to make B2C calls. We would like to use Skype for Business api to do that. I found a source on how to use Skype for Business with iOS and Android:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/appsdk/embedskypeb2ccomms

What I cannot find is how to use the api with Xamarin.Forms. I would appreciate if somebody could refer me to the info.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic"

Comment: @Jason I don't understand how a question on finding resource on a particular programming topic can be off-topic.Plus, it doesn't have to be a book or tutorial. One may use just his own words to help. This site is full of such questions and answers.

Comment: Because those are the rules of SO.  Among other things, links go stale and that makes questions with simple link answer of limited value.  It also discourages people from searching for answers themselves before asking.

Comment: @Jason I did search, and you can see it in my question itself. Links do go stale, and yet they are used here every time. I cannot believe the rules prohibit using them.

Comment: Please don't argue with me about the site rules, I didn't write them.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/

Comment: @Jason Thank you. If you make this an answer, I will mark it.